# Load Cell ADC HX711 Alternatives?

Tags: adc, load-cell, sourcing

Looking for an HX711 ADC alternative.  Sparkfun sells a [pricey breakout board with the chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879), but I cannot source the IC anywhere online for some reason ‍♂️. Are there any ADCs out there that have a built-in instrumentation op-amp?

My current plan is to hook-up my load cell to a stand-alone instrumentation op-amp and funnel that into the ADC of my MCU. However, since my design requires **4x** of this circuit, I would much rather free up some MCU cycles and off-load these duties to a dedicated IC. Any ideas?

Comment: Look for an ADC with an inbuilt PGS. Shopping is off-topic BTW.

Comment: They're a Chinese part so look at Chinese distributors.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for the suggestion . I know its off-topic but HX711 + strain gauge seems like the suggested solution via google, so others might find this thread useful if they need an alternative (as it can't be easily sourced)

Comment: This is not that sort of site and "others" are to be cautioned that this site is not for shopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a parametric search at a distributor such as Digikey for various 24-bit ADCs that work down to DC. Expect to pay 10-100x more than the Avia part.

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

How to use a cheap HX711 module?

---

***Answer***

I have been using cheap cheap US$1 HX711 modules like [this](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32883776006.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.5aa11a051dYiRe&algo_pvid=69cf7905-dc01-444a-8a5e-c733fc57ea2c&algo_expid=69cf7905-dc01-444a-8a5e-c733fc57ea2c-9&btsid=0ab6f82c15954687137722438efa48&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) (Ref 1):

---

***References***

(1) [AliExpress HX711 WeighingPressure Sensor Dual Channel 24 Bit Precision ADC Module - US$1](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32883776006.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.5aa11a051dYiRe&algo_pvid=69cf7905-dc01-444a-8a5e-c733fc57ea2c&algo_expid=69cf7905-dc01-444a-8a5e-c733fc57ea2c-9&btsid=0ab6f82c15954687137722438efa48&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

(2) [HX711 Forum Discussion - rpi.org.forum, 2018nov17](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=227137)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - HX711 Module Wiring and Configuration*

[image: hx711 1]

---

[image: hx711 2]

---

End of answer